# Getting incorrect value reading from arrray

Tags: java

The problem is when I create three accounts for example 1, 2 and 3. Then delete 2 and add a new one the result is 1, 3 and 2, everything ok. When I add another account the results is 1, 3, 2, 3. Adding yet another one gets me 1, 3, 2, 3, 4. 
The values are stored in a text file from where the array reads and writes them to.

The problem is I get the same account number twice. Also just making it always increment by one isn't ok, because I need it to fill the gaps from the deleted accounts.

Can't figure out the problem and would really appreciate some help!

The code responsible:

```
private int choice;
public String name;
public int accountNr = 1;
public int cash;
public int funds;
private boolean run = true;
private int index = 0;
private int index1 = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Account> acc = new ArrayList<Account>();
ArrayList<TransferHistory> transferHistory = new ArrayList<TransferHistory>();
public int c;
public int amount;
private int c1;
private int size;
ReaderWriter io = new ReaderWriter();
private int account0;
private Account ac;
private int account1;
private int account3;
private int account2;
private int viewAnswer;
private int deleteAnswer;
private String s = "";

public void startMessage() {
    System.out.println("***** Welcome to our bank system *****");
}

public void mainMenu() {
    while (run == true) {
        acc = io.readFromFile();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("**** Main menu ****");
        System.out.println("1. Create a new account");
        System.out.println("2. Deposit/Withdraw from account");
        System.out.println("3. Transfer money");
        System.out.println("4. View the account properties");
        System.out.println("5. View one account properties");
        System.out.println("6. Delete account");
        System.out.println("7. Show transfer history");
        System.out.println("8. Show transfer history for one account");
        System.out.println("9. Quit");

        try {
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid choice");
        }

        if (choice == 1) {
            addAccount();
        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            transfer();
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            transferWithin();
        }
        if (choice == 4) {
            view();
        }
        if (choice == 5) {
            viewOne();
        }
        if (choice == 6) {
            delete();
        }
        if (choice == 7) {
            showTransfers();
        }
        if (choice == 8) {
            showOneTransfer();
        }
        if (choice == 9) {
            quit();
        }
    }
}

public void addAccount() {
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    name = scan.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
            if(acc.get(i).getAcc() == accountNr) {
                accountNr++;
            }              

    }
    System.out.println("Your account nr is: " + accountNr);
    System.out.print("Enter your starting funds: ");
    try {
        cash = scan.nextInt();
        if(cash < 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
        index = acc.size();
        acc.add(index, new Account(name, accountNr, cash)); //Add new account object to specified element in acc arraylist
        index = acc.size();
    io.writeToFile(acc);            
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("The scanner couldn´t read your input, use digits next time.");
        System.out.println("The funds for this account has been set to zero, use transfers to adjust");
        scan.reset();
    }

}

public void transfer() {

    System.out.print("Enter account number to withdraw/deposit to: ");
    try {
        account1 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(account1 > acc.size() || account1 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number!");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter a positive number to deposit and negative to withdraw: ");
    try {
        funds = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number!");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size() + 1; i++) {
        if (account1 == i) {
            if (funds > 0) {
                acc.get(account1 - 1).setCash(funds + acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash());
                System.out.println("The amount is changed to " + acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash());
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
                transferHistory.add(index1, new TransferHistory(account1, funds, account1));
                io.writeTransferedToFile(transferHistory);
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
            }
            if (funds < 0 && funds + acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash() > 0) {

                acc.get(account1 - 1).setCash(funds + acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash());
                System.out.println("The amount is changed to " + acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash());
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
                transferHistory.add(index1, new TransferHistory(account1, funds, account1));
                io.writeTransferedToFile(transferHistory);
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
            } else if (acc.get(account1 - 1).getCash() + funds < 0) {
                System.out.println("This transaction is not allowed since the balance will be negative");
            }
        }
    }


    io.writeToFile(acc);
}

public void view() {
    acc = io.readFromFile();
    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("Account name: " + acc.get(i).tempName);
        System.out.println("Account number: " + acc.get(i).tempAccNr);
        System.out.println("Funds: " + acc.get(i).tempCash);
    }
    if (acc.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No accounts to show");
    }

}

public void quit() {
    System.exit(0);
}

private void transferWithin() {
    System.out.print("Enter account you want to transfer from: ");
    try {
        account3 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(account3 > acc.size() || account3 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Enter a account number: ");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter amount you want to transfer: ");
    try {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter account you want to transfer to: ");
    try {
        account2 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(account2 > acc.size() || account2 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Enter a account number:");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size() + 1; i++) {
        if (i == account3) {
            c = acc.get(i - 1).getCash();
            if (c - amount >= 0) {
                acc.get(i - 1).setCash(c - amount);
                System.out.println("Funds in account: " + acc.get(i - 1).getAcc() + " " + acc.get(i - 1).getCash());
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
                transferHistory.add(index1, new TransferHistory(account3, amount, account2));
                io.writeTransferedToFile(transferHistory);
                index1 = transferHistory.size();
            } else if (c - amount < 0) {
                System.out.println("Not enough funds in account");
                mainMenu();
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < acc.size() + 1; j++) {
        if (j == account2) {
            c1 = acc.get(j - 1).getCash();
            acc.get(j - 1).setCash(c1 + amount);
            System.out.println("Funds in account " + acc.get(j - 1).getAcc() + " " + acc.get(j - 1).getCash());
        }
    }
    io.writeToFile(acc);
}

private void viewOne() {
    System.out.println("Enter account number you want to look at");
    try {
        viewAnswer = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(viewAnswer > acc.size() || viewAnswer <= 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a account number!");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size() + 1; i++) {
        if (i == viewAnswer) {
            System.out.println("Account name: " + acc.get(i - 1).getName());
            System.out.println("Account nr: " + acc.get(i - 1).getAcc());
            System.out.println("Funds: " + acc.get(i - 1).getCash());
        }
    }
}

private void delete() {
    System.out.print("Enter account you want to delete: ");
    try {
        deleteAnswer = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(deleteAnswer > acc.size() || deleteAnswer < 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a account number!");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
        if (acc.get(i).getAcc() == deleteAnswer) {
            acc.remove(i);
            io.writeToFile(acc);
        }

    }
}

private void showTransfers() {
    transferHistory = io.readTransferedFromFile();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("***Transactions***");
    System.out.println(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < transferHistory.size(); i++) {
        int t = transferHistory.get(i).tempFromAccount;
        int t1 = transferHistory.get(i).temptransfered;
        int t2 = transferHistory.get(i).tempToAccount;
        System.out.println("Transfer from: " + t);
        System.out.println("Transfered amount: " + t1);
        System.out.println("Transfered to: " + t2);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

private void showOneTransfer() {
    transferHistory = io.readTransferedFromFile();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("***Transactions***");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.print("Enter account nr: ");
    int z = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Transactions made my account nr "+z+":");
    for (int i = 0; i < transferHistory.size(); i++) {
        if(transferHistory.get(i).tempFromAccount == z){
        int t = transferHistory.get(i).tempFromAccount;
        int t1 = transferHistory.get(i).temptransfered;
        int t2 = transferHistory.get(i).tempToAccount;
        System.out.println("Transfer from: " + t);
        System.out.println("Transfered amount: " + t1);
        System.out.println("Transfered to: " + t2);
        System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here I populate the array from the file:

```
public ArrayList<Account> readFromFile() {
    FileReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<Account> result = new ArrayList<Account>();
    try {
        reader = new FileReader(new File(text));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String row = br.readLine();
        while (row != null) {
            String[] splits = row.split(":");
            if (splits.length == 3) {
                int saveNR = Integer.valueOf(splits[1]);
                int saveAmount = Integer.valueOf(splits[2]);
                String saveName = splits[0];
                result.add(new Account(saveName,saveNR,saveAmount));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error in file format");
            }
            row = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading from file");
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ignore");
        }
        return result;
    }
}

private void delete() {
    System.out.print("Enter account you want to delete: ");
    try {
        deleteAnswer = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(deleteAnswer > acc.size() || deleteAnswer < 0){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.reset();
        return;                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a account number!");
        scan.reset();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
        if (acc.get(i).getAcc() == deleteAnswer) {
            acc.remove(i);
            io.writeToFile(acc);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `acc`? looks like some kind of list, show us code part related to `array / list` definition. How are you removing the item from your `array / list`?

Comment: The subject mentions "reading from array"...where's the array?

Comment: What is `accountNr`? Can you show the code where you're adding an account ? Are `1, 3, 2, 3, 4` accounts number?

Comment: The given information is not enough to figure the problem out. Please give us more information and then we try to help you as well.

Comment: Where do you increase or decrease your accountNr? I am sure that the problem comes from *accountNr*  but I cannot see where it will be decreased in your code.

Comment: Maybe sort by account number, then add 1 to the highest for the new account number. Or iterate through once, keeping track of the highest number.

Comment: the 5th line in addAccount() I increment it. Don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: @user2479477 I dont see the part where you are removing array element.

Comment: added the deleteing method

Comment: ok, added the whole class now.

Comment: @user2479477 Try using `if (acc.contains(deleteAnswer)) ` instead of `if (acc.get(i).getAcc() == deleteAnswer) `

Comment: Smit, by replacing it, it doesn't delete anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a counter, have it be a static variable on the class and increment it when you need a new value.  Something like:

```
private static int counter = 0;
private static int nextCounter() {
    return ++counter;
}
```

Or, for synchronization reasons, use

```
private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
private static int nextCounter() {
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

However, I suggest you stop thinking that you need to fill in all the gaps in the account numbers. Typically in database work, account numbers are never reused.  You aren't formally using a database, but you should work the same way.  Reuse buys you nothing, and there is always a chance your code may confuse a new user 17 with the an old user 17.  Just imagine what would happen were the US Social Security Administration were to reuse social security numbers.

Here's the reason for your error, by the way.  In the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
    if(acc.get(i).getAcc() == accountNr) {
        accountNr++;
    }              
}
```

Suppose accountNr starts as 1, there are 3 accounts, and they have account numbers 2, 1, 3.  After each runthrough of the loop, accountNr changes to:

```
1 ⇢ 1⇢ 2 ⇢ 2.
```

`2` is an existing accont number, but your code sets account number to 2 after the last time it would be checked.

### Getting the first unused integer

You want a way to get the first unused integer in `acc`.  Here goes:

```
private int firstUnusedId(List<Account> accounts) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    // Foreach loop.
    for(Account account: accounts) {
        ids.add(account.getAcc());
    }
    Collections.sort(ids);
    for (int index = 0; index < ids.size(); ++index) {
        if (ids.get(index) != index + 1) {
            return index + 1;
        }
    }
    return ids.size() + 1;
}
```

If the `ids` are 2, 1, 5 then they sort to 1, 2, 5.  Then the loop compares:

```
index = 0, index + 1 = 1, compare to 1, equal.
index = 1, index + 1 = 2, compare to 2, equal.
index = 2, index + 1 = 3, compare to 5, not equal, return 3.
```

If the ids were 3, 2, 1, they would sort to 1, 2, 3, and the only difference would be the last comparison:

```
index = 2, index + 1 = 3, compare to 3, equal.
return size + 1 = 4.
```

Comment: Some teachers don't know that much about the real world.  Given the requirement, write a `nextCounter()` method to search for the first unused integer.  You should synchronize things however; threads can interfere with each other.

Comment: Don't really know how I would do that. :/

Comment: Forgetting about synchronization--probably that will come up later in your coursework, create an ArrayList<Integer>`, put all the existing account numbers in the list, sort the list with Collections.sort(List), and search for the smallest positive integer not in the list.  Do you see why that requirement irritates me?  And I've had to implement the exact same requirement in my job too.

Comment: `public void getNumber() {
            for (int i= 0; i < acc.size(); i++) {
                numbers.add(acc.get(i).getAcc());
            }
            Collections.sort(numbers);
    }`

Stuck again..

Answer (score 0):

You must share more of you code but from what i have seen and predict that you are creating the new account from the last accountNr +1 so if your last account in the list is 2 then 3 will be created ...4 etc..so review your new account and set your `accountNr = acc.size+1`